# Detect network card ID in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to know network card id of the user host computer from where the request is coming like IP address. I am interesting to know if it is possible at IIS or asp.net level or any other possible way of knowing it?

Answer (score 4):

As far as getting network card information is concerned, I see little hope for you here seeing as a client's hardware profile is not something naturally pushed down the wire as a matter of course, however see:

`HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress`

Or

`HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("remote_addr")`

This value will give you the IP address of the calling client, although they may be hitting you through a proxy and therefore can't be guaranteed to be a machine specific address.

Answer (score 0):

If by "network card ID" you mean the Ethernet MAC address, that's assuming a particular technology on the remote side that you have no way of knowing whether or not it is used. Sure, Ethernet is used pretty much everywhere these days, but are you willing to limit yourself to clients that use that particular hardware architecture? So even if it were possible, I doubt you'd want to go down that route.

If what you want is a unique identifier per client computer, you are probably better off issuing some sort of token yourself. A cookie with a randomly generated session ID should work fairly well.

Comment: If I can find Ethernet MAC address from the request that is better. If client is using any other technology in which case I can't get it then that will also work for me. Question is I cannot find MAC address from HttpContext object. Is there any other way of knowing it from the Http request?

Comment: @kumar: AFAIK, no. And I recently asked a question relating to this, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864704/determining-users-uniquely-on-a-per-visit-basis.

Comment: That is sad. I could not figure out the reason why MAC address is not transmitted over the internet as most people say. IP address is not reliable if it is not static but MAC address could be had it been sent along with the request.